# DS3234 RTC with ESP32 spi communication error

Tags: c, time, esp8266, spi, esp32

i am trying to learn protocols and ESP32. I am a Arduino user, but i want to move to ESP32 with eclipse , not using arduino ide at all.

I am trying to user DS3234 rtc with SPI communication but i can not make it work.

First i have set the RTC with Arduino and everything worked perfect also the 1Hz pulse was fine (blinking led). Then i tried first to read only from ESP32 but i can not make it work.

I tried pins from SPI2 (HSPI_HOST) from API reference site and also the pinout from the spi_master template, in mode 1 and 3 based on what mode is used in Arduino .ide (i also tried mode 0) , I tried freq of 1,4,10,16,80MHz for Spi_freq. Arduino SPI frequency is 4MHz.

From API reference in Espressif site:
GPIO Number
CS0* 15
SCLK 14
MISO 12
MOSI 13

I also tried to set manually CS to low and high at the beginning and end of transmission also by setting
Code: [Select all] [Expand/Collapse]

```
spi_device_interface_config_t.spics_io_num=-1
```

GeSHi © Codebox Plus Extension
. I am giving you the main.c file and the output that i have.

I am using time.h and time() function to get system time but as you will see in the output this also does not give correct hour, also even trying to set 0:00:00 of Tue 1 Jan of 1970 to rtc does not work cause you will see that the return of Read function is 0:00:00 1 as day 2000-1-1 which is not correct and also there is no change in secs.

May main concern is if there is a problem in my spi setup about ,bus ,dev, initialization etc. If anyone can help it will be great. Thanks.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdbool.h"
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "esp_system.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "driver/gpio.h"
#include "driver/spi_master.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "time.h"

#define MISO 12
#define MOSI 13
#define CLK 14
#define CS 15

#define PIN_NUM_MISO 25
#define PIN_NUM_MOSI 23
#define PIN_NUM_CLK  19
#define PIN_NUM_CS   22

#define SQW_1Hz 0b00000000;
#define WRITE_CONTROL_REG 0x8E
#define READ_CONTROL_REG 0x0E
#define WRITE_TIME_REG 0x80
#define READ_TIME_REG 0x00


spi_device_handle_t spi;
spi_bus_config_t busCfg;
spi_device_interface_config_t devCfg;


uint8_t bcdToInt(uint8_t bcd){
    return bcd-6*(bcd>>4);
}

uint8_t intToBcd(uint8_t dec){
    return dec+6*(dec/10);
}

uint8_t bcdTo24Hour(uint8_t bcdHour){
    uint8_t hour;
    if(bcdHour&0x40){
        bool isPm = ((bcdHour& 0x20)!=0);
        hour=bcdToInt(bcdHour& 0x1f);
        if(isPm){
            hour+=12;
        }
    }else{
        hour= bcdToInt(bcdHour);
    }
    return hour;
}


void spiInit(){

    busCfg.miso_io_num=MISO;
    busCfg.mosi_io_num=MOSI;
    busCfg.sclk_io_num=CLK;

//  busCfg.miso_io_num=PIN_NUM_MISO;
//  busCfg.mosi_io_num=PIN_NUM_MOSI;
//  busCfg.sclk_io_num=PIN_NUM_CLK;
    busCfg.quadhd_io_num=-1;
    busCfg.quadwp_io_num=-1;

    spi_bus_initialize(HSPI_HOST,&busCfg,2);

    vTaskDelay(100/portTICK_PERIOD_MS);

    devCfg.mode=1;
    devCfg.clock_speed_hz=1*1000*1000;
    devCfg.spics_io_num=CS;
    devCfg.queue_size=7;

    spi_bus_add_device(HSPI_HOST,&devCfg,&spi);

    vTaskDelay(100/portTICK_PERIOD_MS);

//  gpio_pad_select_gpio(PIN_NUM_CS);
//  gpio_set_direction(PIN_NUM_CS,GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);
//  gpio_set_level(PIN_NUM_CS,1);

//  gpio_pad_select_gpio(CS);
//  gpio_set_direction(CS,GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);
//  gpio_set_level(CS,1);

}

void setCS(){

    gpio_set_level(CS,0);
}

void unsetCS(){
    gpio_set_level(CS,1);
}

void setControlReg(const uint8_t cmd){


    esp_err_t ret;
    spi_transaction_t t;
    memset(&t,0,sizeof(t));
    t.length=8;
    t.tx_buffer=&cmd;
    ret=spi_device_transmit(spi,&t);

    assert(ret==ESP_OK);
}
void setTime(const uint8_t *data,uint8_t cmd,int len){

    //setCS();
    setControlReg(cmd);

    esp_err_t ret;
    spi_transaction_t t;
    memset(&t,0,sizeof(t));
    t.length=len*8;
    t.tx_buffer=&data;
    ret=spi_device_transmit(spi,&t);
    assert(ret==ESP_OK);
    //unsetCS();
}

uint8_t* readData(const uint8_t cmd,int len,uint8_t *data){

    //setCS();
    setControlReg(cmd);

    esp_err_t ret;
    spi_transaction_t t;
    memset(&t,0,sizeof(t));
    t.length=len*8;
    t.flags=SPI_TRANS_USE_RXDATA;
    ret=spi_device_transmit(spi,&t);
    //printf("Get Data result");
    assert(ret==ESP_OK);

    //unsetCS();

    data=t.rx_data;

    return data;

}

void print_time(struct tm tm){

    printf("Time: %i:%i:%i %i Day %i-%i-%i\n",tm.tm_hour,tm.tm_min,tm.tm_sec,tm.tm_wday,tm.tm_year+2000,tm.tm_mon+1,tm.tm_mday);
}

uint8_t* timeToBuffer(uint8_t *data,struct tm tm){
    printf("Time to buffer");
    print_time(tm);
    data[0]=intToBcd(tm.tm_sec);
    data[1]=intToBcd(tm.tm_min);
    data[2]=intToBcd(tm.tm_hour);
    data[3]=intToBcd(tm.tm_wday);
    data[4]=intToBcd(tm.tm_mday);
    data[5]=intToBcd(tm.tm_mon);
    data[6]=intToBcd(tm.tm_year);

    return data;

}

void bufferToTime(struct tm *tm,uint8_t *buffer){


    tm->tm_sec=bcdToInt(buffer[0]);
    tm->tm_min=bcdToInt(buffer[1]);
    tm->tm_hour=bcdTo24Hour(buffer[2]);
    tm->tm_wday=bcdToInt(buffer[3]);
    tm->tm_mday=bcdToInt(buffer[4]);
    tm->tm_mon=bcdToInt(buffer[5]);
    tm->tm_year=bcdToInt(buffer[6]);

}


void app_main(void)
{
    printf("Initializing SPI\n");
    spiInit();

    printf("Set Time\n");

    uint8_t bufferData[7];
    memset(bufferData,0,sizeof(bufferData));

    time_t curTime;
    time(&curTime);
    printf("%s\n",ctime(&curTime));
    struct tm *myTime=localtime(&curTime);


    setTime(timeToBuffer(bufferData,*myTime),WRITE_TIME_REG,7);
    memset(bufferData,0,sizeof(bufferData));

    printf("Start Reading\n");
    while (true) {
        readData(READ_TIME_REG,7,bufferData);
        bufferToTime(myTime,bufferData);
        print_time(*myTime);
        vTaskDelay(1000/portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    }
}
```

Output:

> Initializing SPI
>
> Set Time
>
> Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 1970
>
> Time to bufferTime: 0:0:0 4 Day 2070-1-1
>
> Start Reading
>
> Time: 0:0:0 0 Day 2000-1-0
>
> Time: 0:0:0 0 Day 2000-1-0
>
> Time: 0:0:0 0 Day 2000-1-0

Comment: What development board are you using?

Comment: esp32 devkitC-ver4

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

Set of time is working properly. On read i had to comment out the flag and set the t.rx_buffer to the data variable. SO the code in this function works like.

```
uint8_t* readData(const uint8_t cmd,int len,uint8_t *data){

    setCS();
    setControlReg(cmd);

    esp_err_t ret;
    spi_transaction_t t;
    memset(&t,0,sizeof(t));
    t.length=len*8;
    //t.flags=SPI_TRANS_USE_RXDATA;
    //t.tx_buffer=data;
    t.rx_buffer=data;
    ret=spi_device_transmit(spi,&t);
    //printf("Get Data result");
    assert(ret==ESP_OK);

    unsetCS();

    //data=t.rx_data;

    return data;

}
```